# Android GreenDao conditional unique property

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator, greendao3

How can I create conditional unique property with greendao?
I have an entity and I would like to create two unique property, but with a condition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible right now, as dao generator run as a separate module and it runs independently hence you can't write something conditional based on your app .